# How to view the code of an ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

I created an ADO.NET Entity Data Model. Where can I go to check the actual class? I want to check the data types and add some `DisplayName` attributes.

Here is the model from the Solution Explorer:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/create-poco-entity.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you generate a model from a database (which appears to be the case here), a few different code files are created. To get the code for the context, expand `ProgramMasterList.Context.tt`. You'll see a .cs file in there for the context class.

Then, for each table you selected from your database to be part of the model, an entity class is created. You can find those by expanding `ProgramMasterList.tt`. For instance, if you have a table called Person, you might have an entity class file `Person.cs` with the `Person` class defined in it.

Now, you mentioned wanting to modify the classes to add properties. If you modify the class files under `ProgramMasterList.tt`, which are dynamically generated by the Entity Framework, then the next time you update your model from the database (such as to add a new table from your DB to your model), any changes you've made will be overwritten. Fortunately, there's a better way. Each class under `ProgramMasterList.tt` is a *partial* class. So, you can add to that class without modifying the file that the Entity Framework automatically generated. Just create a new file, declare the Person class (as partial), and add your extra methods, properties, etc. in there. I'd suggest putting all such "extensions" into a folder to keep them organized, but that's up to you.

So, it might look something like this:

Solution structure:

- ProgramMasterList.edmx

  - ProgramMasterList.Context.tt

    - ProgramMasterList.Context.cs
  - ProgramMasterList.Designer.cs
  - ProgramMasterList.edmx.diagram
  - ProgramMasterList.tt

    - Person.cs
- Extensions

  - Person.cs

Person.cs (under ProgramMasterList.tt)

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Person
    {
        public Person()
        {
        }

        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Person.cs (in the Extensions folder)
  Note: make sure the Namespace exactly matches the namespace from the other Person.cs file.

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public partial class Person
    {
        // Custom property (not auto-generated by Entity Framework)
        public string DisplayName
        {
            get { return PersonID + " - " + Name + " (" + Birthdate.ToString() + ")"; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. How do you add attributes like`[Key]` and `[Required(ErrMessage = " ")]` to these properties?

Comment: Those sort of attributes are more commonly seen on code first models. In database first, you would set the key not by an attribute but through the model editor. Usually, EF does a decent job of automatically determining what column(s) is/are the primary key based on the database structure, but if it gets it wrong, you can right click on a property within an entity to change whether or not it's a key. As for the "Required" attribute, you could make the column non-nullable, but that wouldn't allow you to set an error message. I'd suggest validation with the IValidatableObject interface.